# Global variable not updating in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, global-variables

I've seen several posts on here about how to update a Javascript global variable. I'm trying to use it as a toggle, so that when the function runs again it does the opposite of what it just did (or, that is, whatever I've set it to do. )

It's not working, and I'm frusturated because I'm getting no errors from the developer console, either.

```
var display_menu_toggle = false;
function display_menu() {
        if (display_menu_toggle == true) {
        document.getElementById('barometer').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('finance').style.display = "none";
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('barometer').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('finance').style.display = "block";
    display_menu_toggle = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are never setting `display_menu_toggle` back to `false`.

Comment: Instead of `display_menu_toggle = true;` you need to toggle it `display_menu_toggle = !display_menu_toggle;`

Comment: What about it is not working?  It looks like it should toggle the first time (false to true), but not necessarily to false again.

Comment: @felixKling Thanks! It works. Now, if you want the points you're gonna have to submit it in terms of an answer.

Comment: first of all you don't need to use  `if (display_menu_toggle == true)` you could simply write `if (display_menu_toggle)`. Secondly you should assign a `false` value to `display_menu_toggle` when you are done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you aren't changing the value of *display_menu_toggle* for both conditions. Consider:

```
var display_menu_toggle = false;

function display_menu() {
    document.getElementById('barometer').style.display = display_menu_toggle? "none" : '';
    document.getElementById('finance').style.display = display_menu_toggle? "none" : '';
    display_menu_toggle = !display_menu_toggle;
}
```

It's usually best to toggle *style.display* between *none* and '' (empty string) so that when not hidden, the element returns to its default or inherited style, whatever that might be.